# Not able to query with null values

Tags: sql, db2, case

I need to query based on the parameter, used parameter in the CASE clause.

Parameter will contain these values : contactSuccess,contactFail,notcontacted

We have column : empCommunication which is boolean. It will take 0,1, null

Based on the Parameter value, I need to run the query.

Eg: if Parameter is contactSuccess then Where clause should be
empCommunication = 1

if Parameter is contactFail then Where clause should be
empCommunication = 0

The above two scenario's are working with the below query, but if fails with

Parameter is notContacted, in this case Where clause should be
empCommunication IS NULL.

Kindly help me on this.

```
SELECT
        empCategory as name,
        count(*) as value
from EmployeeRecords R
WHERE empCommunication =
    CASE ?
        WHEN 'contactSuccess' THEN  1
        WHEN 'contactFail' THEN 0
        WHEN 'notcontacted' THEN  IS NULL
     END
group by empCategory
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: `THEN  NULL` instead of `THEN  IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_coalesce.html) to cover the case where the parameter is `'notcontacted'` with a different value like `-1`:

```
SELECT
        empCategory as name,
        count(*) as value
from EmployeeRecords R
WHERE coalesce(empCommunication, -1) =
    CASE ?
        WHEN 'contactSuccess' THEN  1
        WHEN 'contactFail' THEN 0
        WHEN 'notcontacted' THEN -1
     END
group by empCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```
SELECT
        empCategory as name,
        count(*) as value
        from EmployeeRecords R WHERE empCommunication =
(CASE a_column_in_table
        WHEN 'contactSuccess' THEN  1
        WHEN 'contactFail' THEN 0
        WHEN 'notcontacted' THEN  NULL
        else null
 END)
group by empCategory;`
```

Comment: I tired it, it is not working, as it takes the where empCommunication = null instead of empCommunication  is null. The problem is in parameter ( ? ) , I'm not getting values, i'm getting some lables based on that we need to modify the query.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your param is p_param, you could change your query to

```
SELECT
    empCategory AS name,
    COUNT(*) AS value
FROM EmployeeRecords
WHERE 
    (empCommunication IS NULL AND p_param = 'notcontacted')
    OR (empCommunication = 1 AND p_param = 'contactSuccess')
    OR (empCommunication = 0 AND p_param = 'contactFail')
GROUP BY empCategory;
```